# INSERT column Values from dataGridView INTO database table

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

as shown below I have a dataGridView binding with a tb2 table from database,

How can I insert ( res column ) data into tb table ?

[image]

Expected result

[image]

Comment: Please show your code and describe exactly what is not working.

Comment: @Crowcoder I really don't know what is the code to insert these column values into a a database table, I tried to store them into an array and then i used INSERT query but it didnt work as expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you use access as a database

saves the first 3 cells of datagridview the above query is only for 3 and its multiples but this way I could

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand (@"insert into tb
(hb,urea,ca)
Values 
(@hb,@urea,ca)", database.con);
int RowInsert = dataGridView1.RowCount / 3;
int i = 0;
int control =1;
while (true)
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hb", $"{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value}");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urea", $"{dataGridView1.Rows[i+1].Cells[2].Value}");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ca", $"{dataGridView1.Rows[i+2].Cells[2].Value}");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (RowInsert==control)
      {
        break;
      }
    i += 3;
    control++;
}
MessageBox.Show("Success", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Comment: thoughtfulness..Thanks for the warning

Comment: thanks a lot.. but i make some changes into code like Rows[0].Cells[2], Rows[1].Cells[2] and so on to insert only data from res column as a third column in datagridview...now  How can i use for loop into all column data and insert them into db ? and yes i use OLEDB

Comment: just add in foreach `"@ca", $"{dgr.Cells[2].Value}"`

Comment: if you can't i can update the code for you

Comment: this loop insert three rows into database, and all i need is only one row.

Comment: doesn't work neither, where is is other column data (@hb,@urea); in the past i used for loop in query but its always insert many rows, i tried to insert with where condition but it doesnot work too

Comment: the above loop is only for 3 and its multiples but this way I could